# Настройки из админки в ларавел

Tags: laravel

Подскажите, написал свою админку для ларавел, есть страница настройки, как мне сделать чтобы данные указанные на это странице отображались на сайте(логотип, название сайта и др.) мне придется в каждом контроллере вызывать эти параметре и выводить в with([])? или можно как-то обойти это и вызывать во вьюхе сразу как settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализаций может быть море вот одна из них, она хороша тем что использует стандартные функции фреймворка:

В *laravel* есть *helper*`config()`

В официальной документации сказано

> Вы можете установить переменные конфигурации во время выполнения, передав массив пар ключ/значение:

Пример установки - `config(['app.site_name' => 'My blog']);`

Пример использования - `{{ config('app.site_name') }}`

Подробнее в [официальной документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-config)